# Changing innerHTML with javascript in a new window

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to edit the innerHTML of a list item in another window through javascript with the code below.

```
function searchNameButton() //this function is called when the user clicks the search by name button.
{
    name = document.getElementById("nmSearch").value;
    window = window.open("search.html"); //opens a new window, can be accessed through this window variable
    matchIndexes = [];

    for (i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++) //do the actual search here
    {
        if (pokemon[i][1].toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())) //converts to lowercase so that the search is case-insensitive
        { 
            matchIndexes.push(i);
        }
    }

    //now to populate the new page, similar to how it was done before
    itemList = window.document.getElementsByClassName("pd");
    console.log(matchIndexes);
    for (i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++)
    {
        itemList[i].innerHTML = generateString(pokemon[matchIndexes[i]]);
    }

}
```

However, when the new window opens, nothing is changed. I know for sure the matchIndexes is working, I outputted it's value and it's finding 3 matches on my test case (as it should), and similarly, itemList is properly populated with 20 items when I output that to the console. However, changing the innterHTML of any of these items, even doing it outside the for loop as a test, does nothing. I'm unsure what exactly my error is.

The generateString() function, for clarification, works fine elsewhere, and even in a worst-case scenario can not possibly output an empty string. At the very least it would output a few characters that I'd then be able to see in the inspector.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As you should see from the `window.open()` part, `window` is an existing identifier (referring the current window), and as it is a rather special one chances are that you may not set it. Try something else, like `wnd`, `wind`, etc.

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Description) emphasizes that

> Note that remote URLs won't load immediately. When `window.open()` returns, the window always contains `about:blank`. The actual fetching of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the referenced resource are done asynchronously.

As [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#Event_handlers_implemented_from_elsewhere) seems to have an `onload` handler, I would simply try wrapping the window-altering parts into an event handler:

```
function searchNameButton() //this function is called when the user clicks the search by name button.
{
    name = document.getElementById("nmSearch").value;
    wnd = window.open("search.html"); //opens a new window, can be accessed through this wnd variable
    matchIndexes = [];

    for (i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++) //do the actual search here
    {
        if (pokemon[i][1].toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())) //converts to lowercase so that the search is case-insensitive
        { 
            matchIndexes.push(i);
        }
    }

    wnd.onload = function()
    {
        //now to populate the new page, similar to how it was done before
        itemList = wnd.document.getElementsByClassName("pd");
        console.log(matchIndexes);
        for (i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++)
        {
            itemList[i].innerHTML = generateString(pokemon[matchIndexes[i]]);
        }
    };
}
```

But, I haven't actually tried this, so it may or may not work. If it doesn't, I would add some dummy log at the very beginning of the handler to see if it gets invoked at all, and then a `console.log(itemList);` line to see if the `getElementsByClassName()` call finds anything.